# Trying to change game cursor into an image

Tags: javascript, css, cursor

I am making a "smacking" game and would like change the cursor into a png image of a hand.  I tried changing it through CSS and it wont work:

cursor: url('/images/hand.png'), auto;

basically i'm having problems changing my cursor into an image.
do you guys have any suggestions? I am using html, css/sass and javascript

Comment: on what are you setting the css style?

Comment: What browser have you tried this in?

Comment: It should work fine as long as you are using anything except IE (it only uses ani, cur icon files) or Opera which doesnt support it at all. [Works here](http://jsfiddle.net/bLp77u56/1/) for Chrome and firefox

Answer (score 2):

If you want this to be the default cursor on all elements change your css to:

`body *{ cursor: url('/images/hand.png'), auto !important; }`

**EDIT** Make sure your image is 32x32. If the image is too large it wont work.

Answer (score 1):

Should be something like this:

```
$(this).css( 'cursor', 'url(yourimage.png), auto' );
```

take a look the example I have created: http://jsfiddle.net/gon250/2dqscLzz/

I hope it's helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try with jQuery:

```
$("canvas#canvas").on("mouseover",function() {      
  $(this).css('cursor', 'url(Images/hand.png), auto'); 
 }).mouseout(function(){    
 $(this).css('cursor', 'auto');
});
```